# custom navigation arrows for meta slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Following is the code for custom navigation arrows

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#topCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#topCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

following is the php code for slider

```
<?php get_header( ); ?>


  <!--================top slider section starts====================-->
    <section id="home-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
             <!--==============main slider section starts==================-->
            <div class="slider box effect7">

              <?php 
                  echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=20]"); 
              ?>



            </div>
            <!--==============main slider section ends==================-->
```

What more code i need to post

How do i add them in the meta slider wordpress;
Please help me out

Comment: You need to post more code here please edit your post. Include header.php / which ever PHP file includes your slider.

Comment: Why do you want to add custom navigation arrow for meta slider? Meta slider itself provide option to enable/disable navigation arrows. If you wish to change these arrow, you can override them with your css.

Comment: where do i need to put this css? in dashboard or ............????